# How to unpack a list of ints and print them so they have a preceding zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterable-unpacking

I have a list of `[##, ##, ## ... ##]` and I want to unpack it and print it as `"##-##-##-...-##"` with preceding zeros on the left if the number is less than ten.

Is there a way to do this besides a for loop? I don't want the trailing `"-"` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard python [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) + `str.join`:

```py
lst = [1,2,3,99,8]

s = '-'.join(f'{n:0>2}' for n in lst)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
01-02-03-99-08
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `str.format()` as well.

```
lst = [1,2,3,5,10,71,98]

s = '-'.join('{:0>2}'.format(n) for n in lst)
print(s)

#output
01-02-03-05-10-71-98
```